# Microsoft Office 2013 installation via PlayOnLinux crashes

Tags: software-installation, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am having a problem with online installation of MS Office 2013 through Playonlinux on Ubuntu 18.04. I didn't get an ISO, but only a link to Microsoft servers. I tried to install it, but during the installation progress at 58% it suddenly crashes and doesn't progress any further.

I found out that this error, 30175, has something to do with security. On theMicrosoft website it was suggested to disable firewall and antivirus for the duration of the installation process. However, I couldn't find anything related on WineHQ, Playonlinux or Ubuntu Forums. I disabled my firewall but without any success. Probably I have to force Playonlinux to grant privileges for Microsoft to modify my computer. But this is beyond me, I am just an end-user. Could somone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not support this and does also not acknowledge WINE so does not include that in their support options. The link is likely searching for a confirmation you are using an official Windows on your system that WINE does not provide.

I would advice to start using LibreOffice (LO) or OpenOffice (OO). The only thing these 2 can not do is use Visual Basic.You use python for that and would need to re-do macro's so they work with python. For all other purposes it works. You can open and create Windows documents. Things work a little different so it needs a bit of experience. I myself have been using LO for several years (on both Windows and Linux) and have yet to run into something that was not compatible with Windows. Even if you get it to work MSO in WINE will be a worse experience than using LO/OO.

If that is not an option I would advice to install Windows either as a dual boot or virtual in Ubuntu (using VirtualBox or VMWare). This will let you use the link and will provide a far better experience than with using WINE. It also lets you use chemdraw and connect it with MSO. Since with both methods are actually using Windows.
It will require a legitimate Windows to be official.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try this Virtualbox option. As you mentioned, it will let me connect chemdraw with MSO. I am so persisent because everyone around me works with MSO and there is a compatibility issue. It is not that these files will not work but there are always some formatting inconsistancies. Someone who saves a file using MSO will be able to use LO/OO without a hitch, but the opposite situation is more problematic. If someone prepares a file using LO/OO and either saves it as odt or even as doc or docx, there will always be these formatting inconsistencies.

Answer (score -1):

If you're alright with just the NAME being different, there's this un-official Office app, which can be downloaded totally hassle-free with the system app "Ubuntu Software" (and the Snap Store website too, I believe). The name's: Office365WebDesktop. And other than the name being different, it's perfect, almost like an exact replica of the official Office app. Here's [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU7nV.png)